# Can I replace 'make_blobs' with a specific dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I found some very useful code to test a bunch of clustering algos iteratively.  The sample code works fine.  I'm wondering if I can change one line of code to feed in my actual dataset.

```
From:
    blobs = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=n_samples, random_state=8)

To:
    blobs = myowndataset
```

So, 'myowndataset' contains some categorical data as well as numerical data.  I can easily one-hot encode the categorical data.  I'm just wondering if it's possible to do this.  In the sample code everything is numeric.  Also, `'datasets.make_blobs'` seems like it consists of two arrays, and X and a y.  Is that how it works?

The code comes from here.

https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html

Comment: yes you can, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to search for the folder part where the datasets are saved for you, for me it was something like: `C:\Users\...\scikit_learn_data`, if it has the same format you can save it there and load it to keep the same structure of code. This also works if you cannot access datasets directly from the web.

The other option is to rewrite your code and use common pandas libraries `pd.read_csv` to load your data and bring it into the right format.